# How can I get all supported screen resolutions on mac OSX Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I want a code that

1)grabs my current screen resolution, (solved).

For example : to get current screen display code is :

system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType |grep Resolution

2)grabs all supported resolution  as shown in picture below  (unsolved).

or any Objective C code will be also useful

[image]

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you, explain how to write the code, or provide examples or references are off-topic. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and the full text of any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/UeT2tS)].

Comment: For getting current screen resolution   the code is---------------                                                                                        system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType |grep Resolution

Comment: Please edit your question, don't post the code in comments.

Comment: thanks for   helping me out on making question more clearer

Comment: You want code? Good for you. This is a bad question.

Comment: @LeoNatan "You want code? Good for you. This is a bad question. – Leo Natan 5 hours ago" He have asked this question and already answered his own question more than one year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift code

```
    var displayConfig: CGDisplayConfigRef = nil
    let mainDisplayID = CGMainDisplayID()

    var displayMode = CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(mainDisplayID).takeRetainedValue()
    var width = CGDisplayModeGetWidth(displayMode)
    var height = CGDisplayModeGetHeight(displayMode)

    print("current size: \(width)x\(height)\n")
    print("available sizes:\n")

    var modes = CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes(mainDisplayID, nil).takeRetainedValue()
    let modesCount = CFArrayGetCount(modes) - 1

    for i in 0...modesCount {
        var mode: CGDisplayModeRef = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(modes, i), CGDisplayModeRef.self)

        var width = CGDisplayModeGetWidth(mode)
        var height = CGDisplayModeGetHeight(mode)
        print("\t\(width)x\(height)\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension CGDirectDisplayID  {
    var displayMode: CGDisplayMode? { CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(self) }
    func allDisplayModes(options: CFDictionary? = nil) -> [CGDisplayMode] { CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes(self, options) as? [CGDisplayMode] ?? [] }
}
```

---

```
extension CGDisplayMode {
    var resolution: String { .init(width) + " x " + .init(height) }
}
```

---

```
struct Display {
    static var main: CGDirectDisplayID { CGMainDisplayID() }
    static var mode: CGDisplayMode? { main.displayMode }
    static func allModes(for directDisplayID: CGDirectDisplayID = main) -> [CGDisplayMode] { directDisplayID.allDisplayModes() }
}
```

Usage:

```
if let resolution = Display.mode?.resolution {
    print("Resolution:", resolution)
}
for mode in Display.allModes() {
    print(mode.resolution)
}
```