# How to get native screen resolution on OS X (MacOS)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've been searching for a way to get the native resolution of connected displays in OSX, with no luck. NSScreen returns the user selected resolution and the backing resolution, but is it possible to get the real size in pixels?

Basically I am looking for the numbers reported in "About This Mac: Displays" [image: screenshot]

Any ideas? I've seen references to `sysctl` but I have no idea how to parse into that information.

Comment: I am a little curious what you want to do with the information.  Are you trying to collect profiling data, or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780390/shell-script-to-get-all-supported-screen-resolutions-on-mac

Comment: @Khundragpan Thanks - that definitely gets the numbers I need - although damn that is a convoluted way to have to do it.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I am looking into the Arrangement of multiple displays and seeing some strange visual discrepancies that I am guessing can be attributed to the scaling factor of the backing relative to the actual scale.

Comment: @MikeBedar http://stackoverflow.com/a/39539272/2303865

Comment: The alleged duplicate answer doesn't actually answer the question.  If you want to actually find the native resolution (instead of just all the possible resolutions), call CGDisplayModeGetIOFlags() on each mode and check if kDisplayModeNativeFlag is set.  (In C this is defined in IOKit/graphics/IOGraphicsTypes.h, not sure about Swift.)  I'm guessing all the modes have this flag set if the monitor is a CRT.